# Okta get all users list without limit in java

Tags: java, okta, okta-api

I know by using this [Link header](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api-overview/#link-header) we can get the next users and we can get the users list by passing a maximum of 200 as a limit as defined [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#list-all-users).

Is there any way to get all the users present in Okta without any limitations by using java language?

[Here](https://github.com/adrwh/okta-tools/blob/master/Export-AllOktaUsers.ps1) I found a way to get all users in Python. Any solution for Java?

Comment: All you need to do is make a web request to `https://<you okta domain>.okta.com/api/v1/users` and parse the returned JSON- you can find lots of ways to do this in Java, even if you can't find an example doing it with an Okta URL.

Comment: Hello @sleepfuriously  I know we can get the users but I have more than 1000 users in Okta. There is a limitation to get only 200 users at a time. My question is how to get all of them without limit.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to convert the python logic into Java. Here is the working code to get all users:

```
public List<RemoteUsersDTO> getAllRemoteUsers() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    String OKTA_URL = "https:bmg.okta-emea.com/api/v1/users?limit=200";

    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("Authorization", "SSWS " + OKTA_API_KEY);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    String url = OKTA_URL;
    List<RemoteUsersDTO> remoteUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (url != null) {
        ResponseEntity<RemoteUsersDTO[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                url, HttpMethod.GET, request, RemoteUsersDTO[].class);
        RemoteUsersDTO[] remoteUsers = response.getBody();
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = response.getHeaders();
        List<String> links = responseHeaders.get("Link");
        if (links != null) {
            for (String link : links) {
                if (link.contains("next")) {
                    String urlNext = StringUtils.substringBefore(link, ";");
                    urlNext = urlNext.substring(1, urlNext.length() - 1);
                    url = urlNext;
                } else {
                    url = null;
                }
            }
        } else {
            url = null;
        }
        if (remoteUsers != null && remoteUsers.length > 0) {
            remoteUserList.addAll(Arrays.asList(remoteUsers));
            log.info("Total remote users from okta: " + remoteUserList.size());
        } else {
            url = null;
        }
    }
    return remoteUserList;
}
```

Need to optimize it but it is working as of now.

Comment: Were you able to get all 1000 without limit, or was that a separate endeavor than converting the python to java?

Comment: Yes, there is no direct way to do it but I can get all the users by using the above java code hitting the same API with the next 200 users. You will get 200 users in each request, this is the maximum limit by Okta.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Okta's Java Management SDK to list all users like this:

```
UserList users = client.listUsers();

// stream
client.listUsers().stream()
    .forEach(user -> {
      // do something
    });
```

**References:**
https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java#list-all-users
https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java#paging